# How can I calculate means each 3 observations in my dataframe in r?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
RH  Time     Month    Date
45  12:00    March    2017-09-01
48  12:10    March    2017-09-01
46  12:20    March    2017-09-01
44  12:30    March    2017-09-01
31  12:40    March    2017-09-01
```

What I wish to do is to calculate means each 3 observations. I tried it with this code:

```
n.colmeans = function(df, n = 3){
  aggregate(x = df,
            by = list(gl(ceiling(nrow(df)/n), n)[1:nrow(df)]),
            FUN = mean)
}
df <-  n.colmeans(df)
View(df)
```

However, my problem is that the values (RH) get calculated but I get NA's for the Time, Month and Date.
I guess this is because I didn't include the other variables in my function.

I'd appreciate so much your help!

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874203/how-to-get-the-sum-of-each-four-rows-of-a-matrix-in-r/6876475#6876475) helps.

Comment: take a look at [`rollmean`](http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/zoo/html/rollmean.html) from zoo package

Comment: or [rollapply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555788/786542)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It worked, but I didn't figure out how to save the object as a daframe. The object I got is called a "zoo series". Appreciate your time!

Comment: Fixed it! I used fortify.zoo! Damn, R has so many interesting commands haha :d